# how to get cookies id from HTTP header using libcurl

Tags: c, http, cookies, libcurl

the HTTP haeder of my server is like this :

```
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=72D8DC23BD37016CD5557BB353DD008E; Path=/tt/; HttpOnly
SOAPAction: 
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 491
Date: Wed, 03 Jun 2015 14:02:53 GMT
```

how to get  cookies id "JSESSIONID=72D8DC23BD37016CD5557BB353DD008E"  and then using it by my http client.

I used these functions to init http header and send msg :

```
int http_client_init(struct cmp *cmp)
{
#ifdef HTTP_CURL
    http_c.header_list = NULL;
    http_c.header_list = curl_slist_append(http_c.header_list, "User-Agent: cmp");
    if (!http_c.header_list) return -1;
    http_c.header_list = curl_slist_append(http_c.header_list, "Content-Type: text/xml");
    if (!http_c.header_list) return -1;
# ifdef ACS_FUSION
    char *expect_header = "Expect:";
    http_c.header_list = curl_slist_append(http_c.header_list, expect_header);
    if (!http_c.header_list) return -1;
# endif /* ACS_FUSION */
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (!curl) return -1;

#endif /* HTTP_CURL */

#ifdef HTTP_ZSTREAM
    http_c.stream = zstream_open(http_c.url, ZSTREAM_POST);
    if (!http_c.stream)
        return -1;

# ifdef ACS_HDM
    if (zstream_http_configure(http_c.stream, ZSTREAM_HTTP_COOKIES, 1))
# elif ACS_MULTI
    if (zstream_http_configure(http_c.stream, ZSTREAM_HTTP_COOKIES, 3))
# endif
        return -1;

    if (zstream_http_addheader(http_c.stream, "User-Agent", "cmp"))
        return -1;

    if (zstream_http_addheader(http_c.stream, "Content-Type", "text/xml"))
        return -1;
#endif /* HTTP_ZSTREAM */

    return 0;
}


int
http_send_message(struct cmp *cmp, char *msg_out, char **msg_in)
{
#ifdef HTTP_CURL
    CURLcode res;
    long http_code = 0;
    static char *ip_acs = NULL;
    char *ip = NULL;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, http_c.url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, cmp->conf.acs_userid);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, cmp->conf.acs_passwd);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC|CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, http_c.header_list);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, fc_cookies);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, fc_cookies);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, msg_out);
    if (msg_out)
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long) strlen(msg_out));
    else
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, 0);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, http_get_response);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, msg_in);

# ifdef DEVEL
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
# endif

    *msg_in = (char *) calloc (1, sizeof(char));

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if (!strlen(*msg_in))
        FREE(*msg_in);

    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_PRIMARY_IP, &ip);
    if (ip) {
        if (!ip_acs || strcmp(ip_acs, ip) != 0) {
            FREE(ip_acs);
            ip_acs = strdup(ip);
            external_simple("allow_cr_ip", ip_acs);
        }
    }

    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &http_code);

    if(http_code == 204)
    {
        cmp_LOG (INFO,"Receive HTTP 204 No Content");
    }

    if (http_code != 200 && http_code != 204)
        goto error;


    curl_easy_reset(curl);

    if (res) goto error;

#endif /* HTTP_CURL */

#ifdef HTTP_ZSTREAM
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    ssize_t rxed;
    if (zstream_reopen(http_c.stream, http_c.url, ZSTREAM_POST)) {
        /* something not good, let's try recreate */
        http_client_exit();
        if (http_client_init(cmp)) return -1;
    }


    if (msg_out) {
        zstream_write(http_c.stream, msg_out, strlen(msg_out));
    } else {
        zstream_write(http_c.stream, NULL , 0);
    }

    *msg_in = (char *) calloc (1, sizeof(char));
    while ((rxed = zstream_read(http_c.stream, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) {
        *msg_in = (char *) realloc(*msg_in, (strlen(*msg_in) + rxed + 1) * sizeof(char));
        if (!(*msg_in)) return -1;
        bzero(*msg_in + strlen(*msg_in), rxed + 1);
        memcpy(*msg_in + strlen(*msg_in), buffer, rxed);
    }

    /* we got no response, that is ok and defined in documentation */
    if (!strlen(*msg_in)) {
        FREE(*msg_in);
    }

    if (rxed < 0)
        goto error;

#endif /* HTTP_ZSTREAM */


    return 0;

error:
    FREE(*msg_in);
    return -1;
}
```

to set cookies option but the http client doesn't take cookies id from http header of the server so the communication is between client and server will be broken

any help is appreciated

Comment: OK I add the functions for more details

Comment: But this only shows a single request (that follows a redirect). Is it in the redirect you want it to use the new cookies or do you want it to read old cookies from the file and use them and that fails? If so how does the cookie file look like and either way how does the HTTP requests look like?

Comment: read the cookies from file if it is possible. I put already the http request header of the server